# Add Event Listner to dynamically added element using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I dynamically attached a `div` element using jQuery `on` method, but when i attach a listener to the dynamically updated element it doesn't work?

**HTML**

```
<input class="123" type="button" value="button" />
<input class="123" type="button" value="button" />
<div id="footer"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.onlineUsers').on('click', function () {
      $('#footer').append("<div class=\"chatboxes\"> <div class=\"close\"><a href=\"#\">x</a></div> </div>");
  });

    $('a').on('click', function () {
        alert("hello");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As elements are added dynamically you can not bind events directly to them .So you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$('#footer').on('click','a',function () {
     alert("hello");
});
```

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```